# pointing Namechaep domain to the aws lightsail instance(wordpress)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, namecheap

I am new with AWS and i have created the wordpress site on AWS LightSail Instance and created a static IP on the instance for it

Screenshot of the instance:

[image: Screenshot of the instance]

Now my domain is on Namecheap. and i want to connect it with my lightsail Instance.

I have created DNS Zone on the Lightsail > networking tab

screenshot of dns zone:

[image: screenshot of dns zone]

and i have added the Nameservers on the NC domain and they are configured correctly as `whois.domaintools.com` says that the Nameserver have been updated

but the website is still down and error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` displays on the screen. I know there will be very simple fix to it but I am such a noob with AWS.

Please let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: All you need to do is take the IP address of your instance in LightSail and create a new host record (or "A" record) in your zone.  I've actually not used LightSail before so I'm 100% sure how you'd do that.  Perhaps there is a menu for that option on the DNS zone card?

Comment: thanks! I created A record in the DNS zone and put "@" in the subdomain and my static IP in the  Ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks! I created A record in the DNS zone and put "@" in the subdomain and my static IP in the Ip address

Comment: Can you add a screenshot. Tried your solution and still did not work.